# Unable to connect to IBM MQ with TLS using .NET standard library

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ibm-mq

We are getting an exception thrown when attempting to connect to IBM MQ through TLS ({"MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE"}) using the .net standard nuget package, IBMMQDotnetClient.  The project is using .net framework 4.7.2.  We are able to connect without using SSL, and also we are able to connect using SSL when we switch to the .net framework nuget package, WebSphereMQClient, using the exact same code and setup (just swapping out the nuget libraries will allow it to work).

Additionally, I'm not able enable tracing for the .net standard library.  The documentation indicates that the environment varable MQDOTNET_TRACE_ON needs to be set, but even after that I'm not getting anything generated.  I've tried adding other variables like MQERRORPATH but still not seeing any trace files.

**Code**

```
var queueManagerName = "QM1";
var hostName = "hostname.com";
var channel = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN";
var queueName = "DEV.QUEUE.1";
var port = "1414";

var sslKeyRepository = "*USER";
var cipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";

Hashtable prop = new Hashtable();

prop.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, hostName);
prop.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, port);
prop.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, channel);
prop.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT);
prop.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);

prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CERT_STORE_PROPERTY, sslKeyRepository);

prop.Add(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SPEC_PROPERTY, cipherSpec);
            
try { 
    var queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName, prop);
    MQQueue _queue = queueManager.AccessQueue(queueName, MQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

**Error from the client AMQERR01.LOG:**

```
7/16/2021 7:16:12 PM - Process(15212.1) User(Eric.Kaufman) Program(ConsoleApp1)
                       Host(DLW011309) Installation(Unknown)
                       VRMF(9.2.2.0)
                       Time(2021-07-16T23:16:12.121Z)
                       ArithInsert1(0) ArithInsert2(0)
                       CommentInsert1(hostname.com(1414))
                       CommentInsert2(TCP/IP)
                       CommentInsert3( (Exception))
                      
AMQ9202E: Remote host not available, retry later.

EXPLANATION:
The attempt to allocate a conversation using TCP/IP to host
'hostname.com(1414)' for channel 
(Exception) was not successful. However the error may be a transitory one and
it may be possible to successfully allocate a TCP/IP conversation later. 

In some cases the remote host cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Try the connection again later. If the failure persists, record the error
values and contact your systems administrator. The return code from TCP/IP is 0
(X'0'). The reason for the failure may be that this host cannot reach the
destination host. It may also be possible that the listening program at host
'hostname.com(1414)' was not running.  If
this is the case, perform the relevant operations to start the TCP/IP listening
program, and try again.
```

**Error from queue manager logs**

```
07/16/21 23:16:12 - Process(401.18) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(a55a7574679b) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.2.0) QMgr(QM1)
                    Time(2021-07-16T23:16:12.102Z)
                    RemoteHost(XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)
                    ArithInsert1(420)
                    CommentInsert1(????)
                    CommentInsert2(gsk_secure_soc_read)
                    CommentInsert3(XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)

AMQ9665E: SSL connection closed by remote end of channel '????'.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL or TLS connection was closed by the remote host 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'
during the secure socket handshake. The channel is '????'; in some cases its
name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Check the remote end of the channel for SSL and TLS errors. Fix them and
restart the channel.
----- amqccisa.c : 11155 ------------------------------------------------------
07/16/21 23:16:12 - Process(401.18) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(XXXXXXXXX) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.2.2.0) QMgr(QM1)
                    Time(2021-07-16T23:16:12.103Z)
                    CommentInsert1(????)
                    CommentInsert2(401)
                    CommentInsert3(XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)

AMQ9999E: Channel '????' to host 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' ended abnormally.

EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 401 for channel '????' ended
abnormally. The host name is 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX'; in some cases the host name
cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
found in the System Administration Guide.
```

Comment: Do you have access to the logs on the MQ server? They should state why the handshake failed.

Comment: What windows version?

Comment: I have access to the logs on the server, but I didn't see any relevant information from what I looked at (I included the logs from the Queue Manager but the error is generic).  The windows version is Microsoft Windows 10 Pro 10.0.17763

Comment: So, I was able to get tracing to work with the .net standard library but only with .net core 3.1.  .net framework and .net core 2.1 did not allow tracing.

Comment: What did you do to enable tracing? Did you learn anything new from the logs?

Answer (score 5):

This ended up being user error on my part, but I'll include my steps in case it ends up being helpful to someone else.  The environment variables to enable tracing did work but needed Visual Studio to be restarted in order to take into effect.  The three that I ended up using were:

```
MQDOTNET_TRACE_ON = "2",
MQERRORPATH = "C:\MQERRORLOGPATH",
MQTRACEPATH = "C:\MQTRACEPATH"
```

After that the trace file was generated, and I was able to find this exception:

```
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
```

This was because I was using a self signed certificate.  After adding the certificate to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities folder in Windows Cert Manager I was able to connect successfully.

Comment: @Erik Kaufman did you also have another certificate in the 'personal' folder in your certificate store in windows?

Comment: Hey, so basically to get the two way SSL configuration working I had to create a certificate client side and then add that cert to the IBM MQ key database on the MQ server, and then also to create a cert on the IBM MQ server and add that cert to the client (which was done through the Windows cert store).  So yes I had the cert from the IBM MQ server installed onto the windows cert store in the personal folder (along with the intermediate/root certs).

Comment: One obstacle I ran into is that the cert NEEDED to contain the private key to be used, which is indicated by a key icon in the cert store.  Even having the cert in the personal folder did not work unless it also contained the private key.  This took the longest time for me to work through.